# HighLight / ScrollTo - ListView, ScrollView on React-Native

Tags: listview, scrollview, react-native

I'm playing a bit with react-native and I got stuck at a stage where I can't figure it out by myself. I have a list of items and I would like to scroll automatically to some item.

I know I could use the ScrollView and the contentOffset={{x:0,y:0}} and set and offset, however it would be a little bit more complicate because I would need to track the position of each item, I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do it, so I could sort of focus on specific row in ListView.

Is there such a thing available on the libs?

Comment: Great question, I'd be interested to hear the solution as well

Comment: I just came across this. Check it out and let me know if it's helpful https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/ff6a2c39989121b8671ab7cf74a90d048fdc9acf

Comment: Thanks Chris for the hint!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The ScrollView does not provide a method to scroll to a specific list item - but it does provide the methods `scrollTo({x, y, animated})`.

If your list items are of equal height, you can use them to implement scrolling to a specific item by calling `scrollTo({y:itemIndex * ROW_HEIGHT})`.

In order to be able to access the `ScrollView` instance, you need to capture using the `ref` property callback:

```
<ScrollView ref={view => this._scrollView = view} />
```

And set the scroll position elsewhere with:

```
scrollToRow(itemIndex) {
  this._scrollView.scrollTo({y:itemIndex * ROW_HEIGHT});
}
```

Comment: But what if your rows are of variable height?

Comment: @chandlervdw may be you can use https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#measurecallback to measure position, or to measure the heights of all previous rows to the one you want on screen and add them up.
(I know this comment is from >1yr ago, but this shows in google)

Comment: I just found out that SectionList does have a scrollToLocation that receives the index of the section and item. ListView doesn't have this, i don't know why. May be you can use SectionList, including only one section and rendering as nothing, and then use this method. Of course it's not very elegant, but it will probably work better than anything else for rows of variable height (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html#scrolltolocation)

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrollto parameters have changed, updated answer

Comment: For horizontal items, we can use
scrollToRow(itemIndex) {
  this._scrollView.scrollTo({x:itemIndex * ROW_HEIGHT});
}

Answer (score 10):

I have published [react-native-scroll-into-view](https://github.com/slorber/react-native-scroll-into-view), a library which enable "scrollIntoView" feature for React Native ScrollView.

For other lists like SectionList you can still use item index like mentionned in other answers.

Comment: This is a better solution for items in the ScrollView have variable heights.

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `FlatList` instead of `ScrollView`, by using ref you will get access to the scrollToIndex method.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex